# android- Use adjustResize and adjustPan on same Activity

Tags: android, keyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I am Developing a chat app which has background chat image and default keyboard,when i have to use background image it shrinks but when i use   **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** it works perfectly ,but keyboard hides edittext,if i use **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** keyboard displays perfectly but image shrinks,how can i use both option on single Activity

If i use both option in manifest edittext has been hidden

[image]

Comment: try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Comment: l already tried it displays only one feature

Comment: Another way is when your Soft Keyboard is open then make padding to your layout.

Comment: Did you find a viable solution for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'have had the same problem, and I solved it putting `adjust` settings programmatically when it's needed

this is the code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

and

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?authuser=1) those cannot be combined:

> android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
>                                          "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
>                                          "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
>                                          "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
>                                          "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]
>
> The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table, or a combination of one "state..." value plus **one "adjust..." value**. **Setting multiple values** in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — **has undefined results**. Individual values are separated by a vertical bar (|). For example: